# Need a solution for npm install

Tags: node.js

I Got error like no such file or directory open in my path:

```
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\
ge.json'
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON spandana No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON spandana No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON spandana No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON spandana No license field.
```

Comment: What did you to get this error ? `npm install` ?

Answer (score 0):

please uninstall the same module then install it. It should be resolved.